# How to return angularjs scope function asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing a project with `nedb` and `angularjs`.

In `angularjs`, I tried all the way I know to solve the problem below. In this code, I wanted to show the data that found in doc variable. But when I store it to `taken_quizzes` variable and try to return that variable I get undefined every time.

```
$scope.chapterChange = function (chapter) {
   let taken_quizzes;

   score.find({ user_id: $scope.student.id, course_id: chapter }, (err, doc) => {
        taken_quizzes = doc
            console.log(doc)
  })

  return taken_quizzes
}
```

I want to return the result what I find in doc variable that storing to `taken_quizzes` variable.

Comment: Maybe `taken_quizzes = doc` is outside of Angular's scope. Try to wrap `score.find(...)` inside a timeout

Comment: If I do with timeout the function returned value after timeout closed

Answer (score 0):

With an asynchronous API, functions can not return values, they can only return promises:

```
$scope.chapterChange = function (chapter) {
   let deferred = $q.defer();  
   score.find({ user_id: $scope.student.id, course_id: chapter }, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) { 
           deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
           deferred.resolve(doc);
        };
   });    
   return deferred.promise;
};
```

### Usage:

```
$scope.chapterChange(chapter)
  .then(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Deferred API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api)